# Conda environments are no longer isolated

Tags: python, anaconda

Anaconda has become completely broken on my Ubuntu server. In any conda environment, I can import packages all that I installed in my base environment, at a minimum. For example I have a package `ctha_xml` that comes from a private GitHub repository belonging to my company. I can run:

```
conda create -n foo python=3.9
conda activate foo
python
  >>> import ctha_xml
```

and it works, because `ctha_xml` is installed in my base environment. This applies to all packages in my base environment, and all environments besides base.

What can I do to fix this? Could this be something wrong with my environment variables or my `.bashrc`?

`os.environ` inside a conda environment called `text-generation-client` looks like this:

```
environ{'SHELL': '/bin/bash',
        'CONDA_EXE': '/opt/conda/bin/conda',
        '_CE_M': '',
        'PWD': '/home/holmes',
        'LOGNAME': 'holmes',
        'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'tty',
        'CONDA_PREFIX': '/home/holmes/.conda/envs/text-generation-client',
        'MOTD_SHOWN': 'pam',
        'HOME': '/home/holmes',
        'LANG': 'C.UTF-8',
        'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:',
        'CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER': '(text-generation-client) ',
        'LC_TERMINAL': 'iTerm2',
        'SSH_CONNECTION': '10.159.5.25 44390 10.60.244.9 22',
        'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s',
        'XDG_SESSION_CLASS': 'user',
        'TERM': 'xterm-256color',
        '_CE_CONDA': '',
        'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s',
        'USER': 'holmes',
        'CONDA_SHLVL': '2',
        'LC_TERMINAL_VERSION': '3.4.19',
        'SHLVL': '1',
        'XDG_SESSION_ID': '2383',
        'CONDA_PYTHON_EXE': '/opt/conda/bin/python',
        'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1001',
        'SSH_CLIENT': '10.159.5.25 44390 22',
        'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV': 'text-generation-client',
        'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop',
        'PATH': '/home/holmes/.conda/envs/text-generation-client/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/holmes/bin',
        'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus',
        'SSH_TTY': '/dev/pts/8',
        'CONDA_PREFIX_1': '/opt/conda',
        '_': '/home/holmes/.conda/envs/text-generation-client/bin/ipython',
        'KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK': 'True',
        'KMP_INIT_AT_FORK': 'FALSE'}
```

`ctha_xml.__file__` indicates that it is being loaded from

```
/home/holmes/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ctha_xml/__init__.py
```

Comment: Yes, it could be environment variables. Check for one called `PYTHONPATH` and unset it if it's set.

Comment: @darthbith No `PYTHONPATH` to be found. I edited my question to include my environment.

Comment: When you do that `import ctha_xml`, can you print the value of `ctha_xml.__file__`? That'll tell you where the file is loaded from.

Comment: @darthbith The path is `/home/holmes/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ctha_xml/__init__.py`

Comment: It looks like `python` is not loaded from your base env. What does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` print?

Comment: @FlyingTeller `/home/holmes/.conda/envs/text-generation-client/bin/python`

Comment: Interesting. is `/home/holmes/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` doesn't appear to be set, based on both `echo $PYTHONPATH` in the shell and `os.environ` in Python.

Comment: And when in your fresh `foo` env. Does python also correctly come from `/home/holmes/.conda/envs/foo/bin/python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254922/discussion-between-zorgoth-and-flyingteller).

Comment: @FlyingTeller The `~/.local` directory is automatically added to Python's site path if it exists. So PYTHONPATH doesn't need to be set. It's also added before any "system" level packages from the environment, so those will get picked up first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7173), I learned that I can run

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-ecosystem-user-package-isolation
```

to solve this problem. You will need to deactivate and activate your environment afterwards, or you will not be able to import any packages. One can also set `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`, but that messes up the base environment if you set it globally.

I still don't understand why this behavior suddenly started happening when it wasn't happening before, or why conda doesn't do the equivalent of the operation I mentioned on every new environment, but the effort of installing one package on each environment is very minimal, so I'm happy with this solution.

Comment: "this behavior suddenly started happening when it wasn't happening before": If you ran `pip install --user`, that would put files into the user site packages folder. A lot of tutorials online ask you to do that, but then it results in problems like this. "why doesn't conda do this": Some people like this behavior, it's been the default for a long time (so changing now would break a lot of things), and there's the workaround you mentioned. It is really too bad that debugging the problem is not obvious. Glad you found the answer!